# SQL Server 2008 - Can't Log On via local SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: windows-server-2008, sql-server-2008, windows-authentication

FYI: OS is SQL Server 2008 (NOT R2).

Yesterday, when I was trying to get Visual Studio 2010 on a remote Win XP machine to be able to debug ASP.NET over the network, I installed Active Directory (and DNS) on my server.

Well, I gave up that.

So, I un-installed Active Directory and now I can't log on to my local SQL Server instance, `MSSQLSERVER2008` (aka `(local)` or `SERVERNAME`) via Windows Authentication. I get this error message:

`Cannot connect to (local). Additional information: Login failed for user 'SERVERNAME\Administrator'. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 18456)`

---

Some possibly relevant info:

- I *can* connect with SQL Server Authentication (but I can only administer a single database with each log in this way...and there are like 20 of em).
- I *can* also still connect via asp.net user SQL Server Authentication (IIS is running on the same machine).
- I *can* also still connect remotely via Visual Studio's "Server Explorer" using SQL Server Authentication.
- Also, My Administrator Account's `C:/users` directory is now `Administrator.SERVERNAME`
- `Start > run > services.msc > SQL Server (MSQSERVER2008) properties > "Log On" = "Local System account" and "Allow service to interact with desktop" is checked.`
- `Start > All Programs > MS Sql Server 2008 > Configuration Tools > SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Properties > "Log on as:" = Built-in account: (Local System)` ("Network Service" doesn't work {Error: `The parameter is incorrect, [0x80070057]`})
- I've tried making a new administrator account and logging on that way but it still doesn't work (same error as with the other account).

---

My thought is that SQL Server is only allowing connections from users from the domain I had set up temporarily with Active Directory. Maybe when I un-installed active Directory it couldn't revert SQL server back correctly? But I have no idea how to fix this or if that is what happened.

**Any** tips or suggestions are welcome...I've tried just about everything I can think of (which isn't much)...so now I'm looking to the professionals.  :-)

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to log onto the SQL server with the SA account (SQL authentication) and remove the SERVERNAME\Administrator account and re-add it back.  When you promoted the machine to a DC, and then demoted it, your Administrator account SID would have been reset.  So the SID the SQL server has to identify the administrator is not valid anymore.

Comment: +1 That's almost verbatim what I was typing up.  sa or another login in the sysadmin role.

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to Google most of what you said first; so many acronyms! lol. I'll give it a shot and let you know how it goes.

Comment: BTW, what I ended up doing was starting SQL Server in single-user mode then logging in with my Windows Account (I forgot the password for sa, I guess) then followed your instructions.